# Identificar seleção de JRadioButton

Tags: java, swing

Criei um código em java com 2 JRadioButtons e preciso que apareça no console qual radio está selecionado, e quando trocar de rádio, aparecer no console também. Já tentei usa o `if(rad1.isSelected()){"Argumentos"}` e a mesma coisa no 2°radio.

Quando o código começa o 1°radio já começa selecionado, porem quando altera para o 2°radio o console não altera. Como eu faço?

Código:

```
/*Biblioteca*/
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

class Layout {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {

            /*cria o layout e a janela */
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prototipo10");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());


            /*Cria os Radio Butons*/
            GridBagConstraints gbc9 = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc9.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc9.gridx = 1;
            gbc9.gridy = 7;
            JRadioButton radMasc = new JRadioButton("Radio1");
            radMasc.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

            GridBagConstraints gbc10 = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc10.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc10.gridx = 1;
            gbc10.gridy = 8;
            JRadioButton radFem = new JRadioButton("Radio2");
            radFem.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

            ButtonGroup grubut = new ButtonGroup();
            grubut.add(radMasc);
            grubut.add(radFem);
            panel.add(radMasc, gbc9);
            panel.add(radFem, gbc10);


            /*Configurações da janela*/
            frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setSize(250, 250);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Você não adicionou listener?

Comment: não sei usar o listener

Comment: Entendi + - como ele funciona li uns códigos na net porem fiquei na duvida: o ActionListener tem que ser implementado no ButtonGroup ou direto no radio?se sim e mais qual outro ele funciona?

Comment: Não, você precisa adicionar a todos os radiobuttons.

Comment: já entendi como implementa ele, ele funciona em todos os objetos de janela tipo menu, Jtextfield, jButton entre outros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa criar um [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) e aplicá-lo a cada um dos radiobuttons que estiver no seu radiogroup:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class JRadioButtonTest {

    public JRadioButtonTest() {

        /*cria o layout e a janela */
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prototipo10");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());


        /*Cria os Radio Butons*/
        GridBagConstraints gbc9 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc9.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc9.gridx = 1;
        gbc9.gridy = 7;
        JRadioButton radMasc = new JRadioButton("Radio1");
        radMasc.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        GridBagConstraints gbc10 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc10.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc10.gridx = 1;
        gbc10.gridy = 8;
        JRadioButton radFem = new JRadioButton("Radio2");
        radFem.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        ButtonGroup grubut = new ButtonGroup();
        grubut.add(radMasc);
        grubut.add(radFem);
        panel.add(radMasc, gbc9);
        panel.add(radFem, gbc10);

        radFem.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        radMasc.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());



        /*Configurações da janela*/
        frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(250, 250);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new JRadioButtonTest());
    }

    class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JRadioButton radio = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
            System.out.println(radio.getActionCommand());

        }

    }
}
```

Leitura recomendada:

- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)